# Should the meta-tag [robots]' tag definition be expanded to include AI generated content or could we create a new tag for it?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, meta

Currently the tag definition of [robots](/questions/tagged/robots) says:

> For posts about various bots operating on Stack Overflow, as well as about the rules surrounding their development and usage. Don't use for posts about the Community bot, use [community-user] instead. Don't use for posts about the Not A Robot badge too, use [not-a-robot] instead.

Could this definition be expanded to include content generated by AI (like ChatGPT)?

We should be expecting more meta questions on AI generated content to be more common in the future (with better and better bots coming along) and having a specific tag point to these is probably a good idea.

The content may not be directly put into answers by actual bot accounts but by users acting like, well, robots.

Or should we create a new tag for it?

Comment: Don't make tags ambiguous. If you think AI generated content deserves a tag, a new one is much better than adding an additional purpose to an old one. That goes for main and meta.

Comment: @ErikA Oh ok... I have updated my question..

Comment: [robots] is specifically for machines automatically interacting with SO; I.e. a stackapp. CGPT is different, because it's an AI. It needs people or a robot to get input and transfer content to SO. AI can power a bot (I.e. be a thing that does a thing to input to provide output in the form of posts or actions), but it isn't the same thing as a bot in this particular context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta tag [chatgpt](/questions/tagged/chatgpt) was created by someone. I don't know if creating a dedicated "chatgpt" tag is the correct way or not; because I guess something like "ai-generated-content" might be more general but for the time being this should suffice.